# Redefinition of  function

Tags: c++, c

I have one file `example1.cpp` with the `main` function. This file must have `#include mylib.h` and `#include lib.h`. File `mylib.h` also has `#include lib.h`. When I try to compile this program, the error `redefinition xyz function` ocurs.

example1.cpp

```
#include mylib.h
#include lib.h

int main(){
//code
}
```

mylib.h

```
#include lib.h

//rest code
```

Comment: Show the code in the header files please and also use copy/paste to show the actual error message

Comment: Are you using include guards?

Comment: @userr902691 If one of these solved your problem please do not forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) the answer that best solves your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap the .h files in #defines to avoid the redifinitions. For example:

```
#if !defined(_MY_LIB_H_)
#define _MY_LIB_H_

// Add your function definitions here...

#endif  // _MY_LIB_H_
```

You can now include it anywhere and the function definition will be read once. Also note that you can use #ifndef depending on the compiler. VC++ for example, allows "#pragma once" if it's version 10 or higher:

```
#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif
```

In this case, you don't need to use the #defines explained above.

Comment: You should remove the leading underscore from `_MY_LIB_H_`. The C++98 standard, 17.4.3.1.2 says: "Each name that contains a double underscore or begins with an underscore followed by an upper-
case letter is reserved to the implementation for any use."

Comment: Similarly there is also a clause in the C99 and C11 standards (question is tagged both C and C++).

Answer (score 7):

You need to put [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header file to prevent it from getting included multiple times during compilation.

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

// Actual header file code

#endif
```